Azure speech to text on container --> speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber Fails with websocket upgrade failed 404
I'm using azure the container speechToText service on prem on an openshift cluster. I use last version: 4.7.0-amd64-fr-fr. On the other hand i have small contenerized flask API that use azure cognitive service sdk to interract with the container, its the only way for me to be able to use websocket protocol in my organization.
For the methods i implemented that use a speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer, everything works fine but with a speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber, the transcription is systematically cancelled with this error:

CLOSING on
ConversationTranscriptionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=edfb67ce81194adebba896e90996e20d,
result=ConversationTranscriptionResult(result_id=614535e47f7b48ba9f7c2b22c1071c07,
speaker_id=, text=, reason=ResultReason.Canceled))
CancellationDetails(reason=CancellationReason.Error,
error_details="WebSocket upgrade failed: Internal service error (404).
Error Details: Failed with HTTP 404 Not Found
ws://..svc.cluster.local/speech/universal/v2?language=fr-FR
X-ConnectionId: edfb67ce81194adebba896e90996e20d Please check request
details. SessionId: edfb67ce81194adebba896e90996e20d")

i'm on redhat rhel8
Here is my code:
host=ws://<service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:80

app.route('/conversation', methods=['POST'])
@handle_file_d
def conversation_transcription(filename):
    
    done = False

    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(host=host)
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=filename)
    

    speech_config.speech_recognition_language=os.environ.get('SPEECH_LANGUAGE')
    conversation_transcriber = speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber(speech_config=speech_config, 
                                                                                audio_config=audio_config)
        
    def conversation_transcriber_recognition_canceled_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
        print('Canceled event')

    def conversation_transcriber_session_started_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
        print('SessionStarted event')

    def conversation_transcriber_session_stopped_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
        print('SessionStopped event')

    def conversation_transcriber_transcribed_cb(evt: speechsdk.SpeechRecognitionEventArgs):
        if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            text = '\tText={}\n'.format(evt.result.text)
            speaker_id = '\tSpeaker ID={}\n'.format(evt.result.speaker_id)
            print(f"{speaker_id}, {text}")
        elif evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            # output.put('\tNOMATCH: Speech could not be TRANSCRIBED: {}\n'.format(evt.result.no_match_details))
            print('\tNOMATCH: Speech could not be TRANSCRIBED: {}\n'.format(evt.result.no_match_details))
            pass
        else:
            pass
    
    def start_transcribing_async_cb(evt):
        print('Start transcribing event')
    
    def stop_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
        #"""callback that signals to stop continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            cancellation_details = evt.result.cancellation_details
            print(cancellation_details)
        nonlocal done
        done = True
        
    conversation_transcriber.transcribed.connect(conversation_transcriber_transcribed_cb)
    conversation_transcriber.session_started.connect(conversation_transcriber_session_started_cb)
    conversation_transcriber.session_stopped.connect(conversation_transcriber_session_stopped_cb)
    conversation_transcriber.canceled.connect(conversation_transcriber_recognition_canceled_cb)
    # stop transcribing on either session stopped or canceled events
    conversation_transcriber.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    conversation_transcriber.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    conversation_transcriber.start_transcribing_async()
    
    
    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)

    conversation_transcriber.stop_transcribing_async()

    return "done"

I've tried using differents version of the python sdk (currently it is 1.37.0 that i use) and differents versions of the speechToText image but i still get the same error.
The transcription never trully starts, it never seems to reach the SpeechToText container.
Many thanks :)

From the error message it seems like the issue is with your connection endpoint url.
Plan 1:
Please enable the SDK logging and check if that gives detailed error logs info.
Plan 2:
Also to ensure the endpoint address is compatible with the container, you can record a log using some SDK release prior to 1.34.0 (where v2 endpoints were made the default:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/ai-services/speech-service/releasenotes?tabs=speech-sdk#speech-sdk-1340-november-2023-release
) so e.g. 1.33.0, and check the value of connectionUrl there.
Plan 3:
Could you please set the v1 endpoint in the speechConfig instead of the v2 endpoint? Here's an example:
speech_config
= speechsdk.SpeechConfig(
endpoint
="ws://localhost:5000/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?endSilenceTimeoutMs=5000&initialSilenceTimeoutMs=1000")

Plan 4:
If it doesn't help try to use:
SpeechConfig(endpoint=
"and give the full connection Url with the whole resource path and all query parameters"

Awaiting your reply.

Hello ! Thank you very much for your feedback. I'm off this week so i cannot try. But i will come back to you next week.

Hello, i tried on 1.37 to use v1 and endpoint keyword instead of  host  -> endpoint=f"{host}//speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?endSilenceTimeoutMs=5000&initialSilenceTimeoutMs=1000" and it worked. Many thanks to you :)

I am glad it is working. Please don't forget to upvote the answer, as it might benefit other community users.
